# Expressing rows in terms of other rows in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

how do I explicitly prove that a matrix of this kind:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\ \:1&1&0&0&0\\ \:0&0&0&0&0\\ \:0&0&0&0&0\\ \:0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

for any base : $$ B={b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5} $$

$A_{\left\{B\right\}}$ will have a row $r_1$ that every other row $r_2$ can be expressed as:

$$ r_2 = \alpha \cdot r_1$$

Comment: What do you mean by "a matrix of this kind"?

Comment: with a 2*2 block of ones and the other elements 0, I wrote only 5*5 example, but the zero block could be larger in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One proof is as follows.  Let $n$ be the size of $A$.
Note that $A$ can be written in the form $A = A_1 A_2$, where
$$
A_1 = \pmatrix{1\\1\\0\\ \vdots \\ 0}, \quad A_2 = \pmatrix{1&1&0&\cdots & 0}.
$$
Let $S$ be the change of basis matrix such that $S[x]_{\mathcal B} = x$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$, where $[x]_{\mathcal B}$ denotes the coordinate vector of $x$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B = \{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$.
The matrix of $A$ relative to a new base will be given by
$$
S^{-1}AS = (S^{-1}A_1)(A_2 S^{-1}).
$$
Using the fact that $S^{-1}A_1$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix and $A_2 S^{-1}$ is an $n \times 1$ matrix, show that every row of the product has the form $\alpha(A_2 S^{-1})$.

Comment: I'm not sure that previously I wrote the question clear enough, so i clarified it. I didn't understand your answer ether, can you write more details. 
Because I don't see how do a I prove it for any base. 
I tried to take some general base and show it with it, but it's seems to be too general.

Comment: @Ilya.K. I didn't understand what you meant by "for any base" before. Now it's clear that you're talking about the matrix of $A$ relative to this new base.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: I dont see how it will be the same alpha. Because S^(-1) can be anything with corresponding any possible elements like: 
s11 s12 ... s1n
s21 s22 ... s2n
...               ...
sn1 ...         snn

so the multiplication of S^(-1)A1 will give me a vector where each element is the sum of the two first S's in S, but they are different, aren't they ? So I don't understand how is it as multiplying by a scalar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same $\alpha$". If I were to guess, I would say that you have misinterpreted the question statement as "there exists one $\alpha$ and one row-vector $r_1$ such that every other row-vector $r_2$ satisfies $r_2 = \alpha \cdot r_2$"

Comment: I believe, however, that the statement is "there exists one row-vector $r_1$ such that for every other row-vector $r_2$, we have $r_2 = \alpha r_1$ for some $\alpha$". In other words, we don't need "the same $\alpha$" for every choice of $r_2$.

Comment: yes, that is what I meant, there exists one alpha and one row-vector r1 and so on. Hm, let me think about the interpretation one more time. 
Oh yeah, that's right its not the same alpha, but some alpha with one row exactly.

Comment: The last comment, that is correct. Ok, that's good, thank you :)